# Printing PHP Array into a string with correct syntax

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array:

```
<?php 

$myarray =  Array
                (
                        'keyword' => 'seo',
                        'title_factor' => false,
                        'description_factor' => false,
                        'headtags_factor' => false,
                        'imgalt_factor' => false,
                        'keyword_density' => 0,
                );


var_dump($myarray);
print_r($myarray);                      


?>
```

Here is the output of vardump and print_r:

```
array(6) {
  ["keyword"]=>
  string(3) "seo"
  ["title_factor"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["description_factor"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["headtags_factor"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["imgalt_factor"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["keyword_density"]=>
  int(0)
}
Array
(
    [keyword] => 'seo'
    [title_factor] => 
    [description_factor] => 
    [headtags_factor] => 
    [imgalt_factor] => 
    [keyword_density] => 0
)
```

Here is what I want as output:

```
    "Array
    (
            'keyword' => 'seo',
            'title_factor' => false,
            'description_factor' => false,
            'headtags_factor' => false,
            'imgalt_factor' => false,
            'keyword_density' => 0,
    );"
```

Comment: As `seo` does not seem to be a constant, you should change `'keyword' => seo, ` to `'keyword' => 'seo',`.

Comment: @str I will edit my post, seo should be a string.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`var_export()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://php.net/var_export):

```
$string = var_export($array, true);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're searching for `var_export` if I'm correct

more info about var_export at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: didn't get a warning there was an answer as i answered only a few seconds later ...